# What is the diference in these two ways of transaction handling

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, transactions

What is the difference in these two ways of transaction handling

**First approach**

```
//
const string selectSatement = @"INSERT INTO Payment....";
using (SqlTransaction sqlTrans = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction())
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectSatement, sqlConnection,sqlTrans))
//
sqlTrans.commit();
```

**Second Approach**

```
BEGIN TRAN T1; 
INSERT INTO Payment....;
COMMIT TRAN T1;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the first option you can have asynchronous use of your database connection (multithreading).

If you have parallel threads performing operations in the database and you simply dump a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` there, you will probably cause other thread's queries that were not meant to be part of this transaction to be included too, and screw something up in case you have to perform a `ROLLBACK`.

With the use of a `SqlTransaction` you make sure only the queries that are supposed to be part of the transaction will be included in it.